# Unable to install SAP crystal report without visual studio 2010

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created a windows application in VS 2010 (C#.net) which prints bills using SAP Crystal report. But i can't install the SAP Crystal report in client machine. It showing an error "Install VS 2010"...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1830352)

Steps I took:

1. Uninstalled the failed installation of Crystal Reports.
2. Removed the C:\Program Files\SAP BusinessObjects directory.
3. Removed all temporary files (using Disk Cleanup and manually deleting all files from C:\Temp and C:\Windows\Temp).
4. Removed the installation directory and re-downloaded CRforVS_13_0.exe from this site.
5. Restarted Windows.
6. Executed the new installation file and entered "C:\CRforVS_13_0" as the directory.

Some additional information:

1. The same error occurs on other Windows XP workstations.
2. All of the machines previously had Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 installed.
3. Verified that installing other applications that use Windows Installer works.